# table-layout:fixed behaves odd on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, css, css-tables

I need to get responsive table, so on small devices I add `overflow-x:auto` to its parent and `table-layout:fixed` to the table.
The code is here
HTML

```
<div class="class1">
  <table class="class2">...</table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.class1{overflow-x:auto}
.class2{width:640px,table-layout:fixed}
```

But on iPhone when I tap to the rows, `tr`-s behave very strange,the height is starting to increase.

Did anyone have the same problem or know the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my experience the problem is not in `table-layout:fixed` or `overflow: auto`. Both of them are working fine on devices. You can try adding `overflow-y:hidden` to `.class1`

Comment: Thanks for answer, not sure if the problem is in that, but now it works. Thanks a lot